# Espresso + UI Automator Test are falling while running them on Jenkins CI

Tags: android, jenkins, android-espresso

I have written some Espresso + UI Automator Test for my app and when I run them locally on my Android Studio using X86_64 emulator the test run perfectly , but when we run the same gradle command on Jenkins CI , my all the test are failing and in the stack trace I am getting "android.support.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)" and java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent". We are running the test on armeabi-v7a because we can not use X86 image to launch the test. Is it because the device is not coming online or in Sleep mode or due to some animations because we are disabling all the animations before starting the emulator using "-no-window -no-audio -no-boot-anim -verbose"